# API Calls with Axios fail on React

Tags: reactjs, express, web, heroku, axios

On handleSubmit i am trying to log in using an API hosted on Heroku and made based on ExpressJS. It is working fine when i am using Postman to reach the API on the login endpoint. But when using axios on react it fails.

Heroku login endpoint :  https://nodejs-mongodb-authapp.herokuapp.com/login

Code :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './Login.css' ;
import {FaMountain} from 'react-icons/fa';
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";

import Cookies from "universal-cookie";



const cookies = new Cookies();
export const Login = () => {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);
   const [state , setState] = useState(false);
   const axios = require("axios");
   
   const handleSubmit = (event) =>{
    
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        email: "au@outlook.com",
        password: "zzz",
      });
      const config = {
        method: "post",
        url: "https://nodejs-mongodb-authapp.herokuapp.com/login",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        data: data,
      };
      
      axios(config)
      .then((result) => {
        alert("in thenn");
    //     setLogin(true);
    //     cookies.set("TOKEN", result.data.token, {
    //         path: "/",
    //       });
    //    navigate('/auth');
        
        
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        error = new Error();
       
      }); 


   }

    return(
       
        <div className="p1">
            <div className="log">
                <form className="formFields" >
                    <div className="lfa">
                        <FaMountain />
                    </div>
                    <p>LOG IN</p>
                    
                     <Form onSubmit={(e)=>handleSubmit(e)} className="form_">
                        {/* email */}
                        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                        
                        <Form.Control
                            type="email"
                            name="email"
                            value={email}
                            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                            placeholder="Enter email"
                        />
                        </Form.Group>

                        {/* password */}
                        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
                        
                        <Form.Control
                            type="password"
                            name="password"
                            value={password}
                            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                            placeholder="Password"
                        />
                        </Form.Group>

                        {/* submit button */}
                        <Button
                        variant="primary"
                        type="submit"
                        onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
                        >
                        Login
                        </Button>
                    </Form>
                </form>
            </div>
            {/* {login ? (
          <p className="text-success">You Are Logged in Successfully</p>
        ) : (
          <p className="text-danger">You Are Not Logged in</p>
        )} */}
        </div>
        
    )
}
```

The API is public for the moment you can try login with those credentials on PostMan :

[image]

Comment: try changing data with the keys as JSON i.e.: `data:{email: yourEmail, password: yourPassword}`

Comment: "It fails" means nothing. Please share everything you know about the error. Also, does you api require the Content-Type application/json header?

Comment: So i've tried changing email and password in plain text it doesn't work neither.

Comment: By "it fails" , i mean it is supposed to redirect the page to "/auth" but it doesn't redirect it and it doesn't trigger any error neither.

Comment: Where can i check in express if it requires this header ?

Comment: Check the updated response, I have tried it in sanbox and it works every time the form is triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I managed to test it and it does respond. The request should be done like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FaMountain } from "react-icons/fa";
import { Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";

const cookies = new Cookies();
export const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [login, setLogin] = useState(false);
  const axios = require("axios");

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const data = JSON.stringify({
      email: "au@outlook.com",
      password: "zzz"
    });
    const config = {
      method: "post",
      url: "https://nodejs-mongodb-authapp.herokuapp.com/login",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      data: data
    };

    axios(config)
      .then((result) => {
        alert("in thenn");
        console.log(result);
        setLogin(true);
        cookies.set("TOKEN", result.data.token, {
          path: "/"
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        error = new Error();
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="p1">
      <div className="log">
        <div className="lfa">
          <FaMountain />
        </div>
        <p>LOG IN (Login State {login.toString()})</p>
        <p>Token: {cookies.get('TOKEN')}</p>

        <Form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)} className="form_">
          {/* email */}
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
            <Form.Control
              type="email"
              name="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Enter email"
            />
          </Form.Group>

          {/* password */}
          <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
            <Form.Control
              type="password"
              name="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              placeholder="Password"
            />
          </Form.Group>

          {/* submit button */}
          <Button
            variant="primary"
            type="submit"
            onClick={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
      {/* {login ? (
          <p className="text-success">You Are Logged in Successfully</p>
        ) : (
          <p className="text-danger">You Are Not Logged in</p>
        )} */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Since you are sending a JSON with the access information through the body, you have to take the JSON structure and then chain it to send it through post, and you have to add the ContentType: application/json header.

UP: When forms are used and you use an input type submit, every time the login button is clicked, the component is updated, to avoid this add the following inside the function `event.preventDefault();`

[Test it here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/morning-mountain-fb8lje?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: yeah sorry the password for this one is "zzz"

Comment: sometimes the api works , but most of the time it doesn't , i've put the whole code above

Comment: and sometimes the alert("in thenn")  in handleSubmit isn't triggered either

Comment: thank you , you are right i had to implement event.preventDefault() and it worked fine